# Sorting vector of custom type by their constant id

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I need to sort a vector of custom type `std::vector<Blah> v` by Blah's integer id. I do this via `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end())` with the operator `<` being overloaded within `Blah` as

```
bool operator< (const Blah& b) const { return (id < b.id); }
```

I noticed that Blah's private id cannot be declared as `const int id`, otherwise the type `Blah` does not meet the requirements for `std::sort` (I assume it conflicts with not being ValueSwappable?)

If `id` is not `const` everything is fine. However, I dislike the idea of the objects not having constant ids just for the requirement of rearranging their order within a vector.

Is there a way around or is this the way it is?

Comment: Id `id` supposed to be unique? If not, you can simply ensure that nothing other than the assignment operator can result in a `Blah` object's id being modified.

Comment: Yes, actually `id` needs to be unique.

Comment: It's not only sort, also vector needs working copy assignment for some operations.

Comment: I'm making a wild guess: you want to sort after the id to be able to access elements by id. For that a map would be more appropriate.

Comment: Very good guess. This is indeed my motivation. I was using a map at first, however, I wondered if I can get rid of it (maps can get quite expensive) and stumbled upon this problem.

Comment: Why not define move and swap operations on Blah. It should then be useable within a vector and there is still no possibility of accidentally duplicating it.

Comment: @RichardForrest you can't swap an object with `const` members.

Comment: @IorisN: Maps are extremely useful data structures. It is true that a sorted vector is sometimes (often?) faster, but use a map until you really see you need the performance - maps are much more convenient.

Comment: I'm relatively sure that you cannot do this, then. Why do you think maps are expensive?

Comment: Can you perhaps make a parallel structure of index values alongside the vector and sort that by `Blah`s const id? (Assuming that lengths don't change if otherwise this gets unwieldy.)

Comment: I'm working on something...

Comment: @DanielJour, EricAlapää. I don't have any data to back up my claim that maps tend to be expensive, however, I repeatedly here it from experienced people. But I definitely can go back using a map and, as it appears at the moment, it seems the right thing to do.

Comment: Yes, you can probably google up some good articles about STL vectors and performance - one reason is that arrays/vectors have good cache locality, which sometimes help performance a lot. But maps can be very good for performance too - for example, they never need to rehash like a hash table, so performance is logarithmic a 100% of the time.

Comment: `const` members of classes are just more trouble than they're worth. My advice would be to have a non-const member but use a naming convention to discourage yourself from modifying it. For example perhaps you could have `private: int _id_internal;` and `public: int id() const { return _id_internal; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way around or is this the way it is?

I fear that this is the way it is. If you want to sort a vector, which is in principle an array, then you have to *assign* to elements when exchanging them.

At least that is what i thought, actually you can cheat a bit. Wrap your objects into an union:

```
template<typename T>
union ac {
 // actual object
 T thing;
 // assignment first destructs object, then copy
 // constructs a new inplace.
 ac & operator=(ac<T> const & other) {
  thing. ~T();
  new (& thing) T(other. thing);
 }
 // need to provide constructor, destructor, etc.
 ac(T && t) : thing (std:: forward<T>(t))
 {}
 ac(ac<T> const & other) : thing (other. thing) {}
 ~ac() {
  thing. ~T();
 }
 // if you need them, add move assignment and constructor
};
```

You can then implement the (copy) assignment operator to first destruct the current object and then (copy) construct a new object from the provided inplace of the old object.

You also need to provide constructors and destructors, and of course this only works with C++11 and beyond due to limitations concerning the union members in previous language standards.

This seems to work quite nice: [Live demo.](http://ideone.com/oA1npo)

But still, I think you should first revisit some design choices, e.g. if the constant id really needs to be part of your objects

Comment: This is an intresting construct. Thank you for sharing. Although I am not going to use it, I accept your answer as it actually answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way around or is this the way it is?

So you want to update / swap the entire data of an object (including it's identity) and to keep the identity constant; the two are in conflict, because constant means "doesn't change" (and swap means "change these instances").

You have stumbled here on the two (competing) definitions of const-ness: conceptual const-ness (what the data says/means is the same) and binary const-ness (the bytes representing the data do not change). (The first definition is what lead to the introduction of mutable in the language: the ability to keep conceptual constness while breaking binary const-ness).

Your data here is conceptually constant (the interface to the data should be const) but not binary constant (you can swap values, so your bits may go away to another instance).

The canonical idea for this is to **keep the data non-const internally, and provide only const public/protected access for client code**.

You say:

> However, I dislike the idea of the objects not having constant ids just for the requirement of rearranging their order within a vector.

Just because the identity is conceptually constant (exposed API is/should be constant), you have no actual hard requirement to keep the data constant (and should have no preference towards it, based on the API).