# Overwriting an object with an object of same type

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, memcpy, placement-new

Is the following well defined?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct Const {
    const int i; 
    Const (int i) : i(i) {}
    int get0() { return 0; } // best accessor ever!
};

int main() {
    Const *q,*p = new Const(1);
    new (p) Const(2);
    memcpy (&q, &p, sizeof p);
    cout << q->i;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that after construction of second `Const`, `p` doesn't semantically (intentionally?) points to new object, and the first is gone, so it is usable "as a `void*`". But the second object is constructed at the exact same address, so the bit pattern of `p` represents the address of the new object.

COMMENT

**`new (p) Const(2)` erase the old object stored at `p`**, so the pointer is not valid anymore, except as a pointer to storage (`void*`).

I want to recover the value of `p` as a `Const*`.

COMMENT 2

After either `p->~Const()` or `memset (p, 0, sizeof *p)` it is clear that `p` does not point to a valid object, so `p` can only be used as pointer to storage (`void*` or `char*`), for example to reconstruct another object. At that point `p->get0()` is not allowed.

Here the demolition of the old object is done by the constructor of the new one, but I don't think that makes a difference.

My intuition is that: **In any case, the old object is gone, and `p` points to the old object, not the new one.**

I am looking for a *confirmation or refutation* based on the standard.

SEE ALSO

I have asked essentially the same question about pointers, in C and C++ :

- [Dereferencing an out of bound pointer that contains the address of an object (array of array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043795/dereferencing-an-out-of-bound-pointer-that-contains-the-address-of-an-object-ar)
- [Is memcpy of a pointer the same as assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048698/is-memcpy-of-a-pointer-the-same-as-assignment)
- [Are pointer variables just integers with some operators or are they "mystical"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045888/are-pointer-variables-just-integers-with-some-operators-or-are-they-mystical)

Please read these discussions before answering "this is ridiculous".

Comment: The `memcpy` should be equivalent to `q = p` simple pointer assignment, shouldn't it?

Comment: @DanielJour I don't think so. `p` is not a valid pointer to an object of type `Const` anymore.

Comment: Why isn't it? It's pointing to a correctly aligned memory area in which an object of the right type has been constructed. (Btw, you should probably add some delete operation)

Comment: @DanielJour The object it was pointing to is dead, erased. The dtor is trivial; say there is a non-trivial dtor and I call it, if you like. (I don't think it makes a difference.)

Comment: @DanielJour Assignment copies pointer value, I want to copy its bit pattern only.

Comment: "Assignment copies pointer value, I want to copy its bit pattern only." The pointer value *is* the value of the bits that you are copying with memcpy.

Comment: "A pointer depends on the state of the program." A pointer like `p` is a simple value type much like an integer. The value `*p` depends on the state of the program, but the value `p` is self-contained.

Comment: [N4430](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4430.html) addresses a similar concern.

Comment: @ChrisBeck "_pointer like p is a simple value type much like an integer_" Obviously not. An integer is not invalid, ever.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: No. For example the fragment `void *p=malloc(1); free(p); printf("%p", p);` is UB because you cannot even print the value of `p` after it has been passed to `free`.

Comment: @curiousguy I think you have a good question here. But I think you're going to have to spell it out a bit because I think most people aren't getting it.

Comment: @curiousguy One could argue that an uninitialized `int` is invalid, in the sense that it is UB to read from it. But once initialized, it remains valid.

Comment: @juanchopanza An `int` object can be invalid, but an `int` value cannot, AFAIK.

Comment: curiousguy: iiuc the only part about your example that undefined is, a conforming implementation is permitted to change the value of p arbitrarily when you call free. if you use `memcpy` instead of `q=p` it doesn't change anything, you are still copying an unspecified value either way, so this whole `memcpy` thing is a misdirection

Comment: @ChrisBeck Not sure what you mean by "a conforming implementation is permitted to change the value of p when you call free". Anyway I could keep  backup copies of p if it was the case.

Comment: curiousguy: having looked at the standard esp. section 3.8 I see this is a good question that I don't know much about, sorry for giving you a hard time. I do think the memcpy thing looks strange though.

Comment: Actually when I look at the stuff in 3.8.5, the code examples following that, and especially what is said in 3.8.5.2 I wonder if it's UB when you access q->i in your example. I'm not sure though.

Comment: *"In any case, the old object is gone, and p points to the old object, not the new one."* - you make a lot of assertions that are blatantly wrong, including this one... would be better to *ask questions* so the disinformation isn't misinterpreted as reliable background info by other readers.

Comment: @TonyD Please prove me wrong.

Comment: @curiousguy: what do you think my answer does?  You're just not listening.  The placement-new ends the old object's lifetime and starts a new object at the same memory address; the pointer `p` remains valid and is left pointing at the new object.  If you slow down to think about it, that should be intuitively obvious, and if it's not I can only echo  Manu343726's advice.

Comment: @TonyD I have changed the question to indicate that this is my personal intuition.

Comment: I don't know if it's appropriate to ask off-topic questions but I now have a lot of questions about how exactly this works. TonyD when you say placement-new ends the old lifetime, does that mean that the original object gets its destructor called, or is that skipped? Or is it undefined what happens if the object has a dtor. (Going to do some experiments / reading now)

Comment: @ChrisBeck If you don't call the destructor, it won't be called.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: the original object's destructor is not called... that does not have undefined behaviour as long as the rest of the program doesn't depend on the side-effects of the destructor.  See 3.8/1 *"The lifetime of an object of type T ends when: ... the storage which the object occupies is reused or released"*, and 3.8/4's *"any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior"*.

Comment: @TonyD "any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior" maybe one of the less intelligible sentence of the standard...

Comment: @curiousguy: overkill too.  I think the provision for reusing the memory is to legitimise effectively discarding old memory pool content - saving time to iterate over and invoke destructors when the objects are of no further relevance.  There must be some good way to word a requirement to meet the natural implementation consequences - that the undestructed overwritten objects are simply irrelevant to the rest of the execution.

Comment: @juanchopanza "initialized" I am not sure what this word means.

Answer (score 5):

(making community-wiki as incorporating dyp's comment re 3.8/7 is very significant; while my earlier analysis was correct I would have said much the same things about code that was broken, having overlooked 3.8/7 myself)

```
Const *q,*p = new Const(1);
new (p) Const(2);
```

The `new(p) Const(2);` line overwrites the object that had been constructed with `Const(1)`.

```
memcpy (&q, &p, sizeof p);
```

This is equivalent to `q = p;`.

```
cout << q->i;
```

This accesses the `q->i` member, which will be `2`.

The somewhat noteworthy things are:

- `std::memcpy` is an ugly way to assign `p` to `q`... it is legal though under 3.9/3:

> For any trivially copyable type `T`, if two pointers to `T` point to distinct `T` objects `obj1` and `obj2`, where neither `obj1` nor `obj2` is a base-class subobject, if the underlying bytes (1.7) making up `obj1` are copied into `obj2`, `obj2` shall subsequently hold the same value as `obj1`. [ Example:

```
T* t1p;
T* t2p;
// provided that t2p points to an initialized object ...
std::memcpy(t1p, t2p, sizeof(T));
// at this point, every subobject of trivially copyable type in *t1p contains
// the same value as the corresponding subobject in *t2p
```

- The overwriting of the old `Const(1)` object with `Const(2)` is allowed as long as the program doesn't depend on side effects of the former's destructor, which it doesn't.
- (as dyp noted in comments below) ongoing access to the `Const(2)` object using `p` is illegal under 3.8/7's third point:

> pointer that pointed to the original object [...] can be used to manipulate the new object, if...
>
> - the type of the original object is not `const`-qualified, and, if a class type, does not contain any non-static data member whose type is `const`-qualified or a reference type ...

- using `q` - rather than `p` - to access `i` is presumably necessary to avoid compiler optimisations based on presumed knowledge of `i`.

As for your commentary:

> Note that after construction of second `Const`, `p` doesn't semantically (intentionally?) points to new object, and the first is gone, so it is usable "as a `void*`".

Given you placement-new an object at the address contained in `p`, `p` most certainly does point to the newly created object, and very intentionally, but it can't be used to manipulate that object under 3.8/7 as above.

Given you seem to have a notion of "semantically pointing" that's not defined in C++ the truth of that part of the statement's in your own mind.

'after construction of second `Const`, `p`...*is usable "as a `void*`'* makes no sense... it's not more usable as anything than it was beforehand.

> But the second object is constructed at the exact same address, so the bit pattern of `p` represents the address of the new object.

Of course, but your comments show you think "bit pattern" is somehow distinct from the *value* of the pointer as applies to assignment with `=`, which is not true.

> `new (p) Const(2)` erase the old object stored at `p`, so the pointer is not valid anymore, except as a pointer to storage (`void*`).

"erase" is a strange term for it... overwrites would be more meaningful.  As dyp noted and explained above, 3.8/7 says you shouldn't "manipulate" the object `p` points to after the placement new, but the value and type of the pointer are unaffected by the placmeent new.  Much as you can call `f(void*)` with a pointer to any type, the placement-`new` doesn't need to know or care about the type of the `p` expression.

> After either `p->~Const()` or `memset (p, 0, sizeof *p)` it is clear that `p` does not point to a valid object, so `p` can only be used as pointer to storage (`void*` or `char*`), for example to reconstruct another object. At that point `p->get0()` is not allowed.

Most of that's true, if by "`p` can only be used" you mean the value of `p` at that time rather than the pointer itself (which can be of course also be assigned to).  And you're trying to be a little too clever with the `void*` / `char*` thing - `p` remains a `Const*`, even if it's only used by placement new which doesn't care about the pointee type.

> "I want to recover the value of `p` as a `Const*`."

The value of `p` was not changed after it was first initialised.  placement-`new` uses the value - it does not modify it.  There's nothing to recover as nothing was lost.  That said, dyp's highlighted the need not to use `p` to manipulate the object, so while the value wasn't lost it's not directly usable as wanted either.

Comment: A bit pattern of a pointer is never invalid. So a bit pattern is not the same as a value. You can copy the bit pattern of an invalidated pointer.

Comment: @curiousguy: `p` was properly initialised so it has a value that can be safely accessed and copied using `=`.  If `p` were uninitialised or deliberately corrupted, then the distinction becomes relevant and it's possible that `memcpy` would be safe while `=` wouldn't.  And BTW - you can copy values of invalidated pointers... the Standard deems a pointer that's not to a currently valid object to have been invalidated, it's different from a bitpattern that doesn't even reference a legitimate address.

Comment: The Bit pattern (*object representation*) contains the value (*value representation*) (§3.9/4) for trivially copyable types, which a pointer is.

Comment: So when you destroy an object, the pointers to this object are still valid?

Comment: Also, are you saying that I can legally modify a `const int` variable?

Comment: @curiousguy: the pointer `p` is not "to" `Const(1)` in some mystical sense - it's to the memory where `Const(1) was constructed, which is the same memory where `Const(2)` is later constructed.  The pointer `p` remains usable throughout.

Comment: @curiousguy Whether pointers to an object are still "valid" after the object is destroyed depends on exactly what you mean by "valid". They would be invalid to dereference to try to access the original object, but they could become valid by the construction of a new object at the same place. Modifying a `const int` variable is not what's happening here. You're replacing the variable with another one, and that's certainly legal. (For example, `a=b;` can do it if, say `a::some_const_variable` has a different value from `b::some_const_variable`.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Then I can also change the dynamic type of an object. :D

Comment: @TonyD If pointers are not mystical then out of array bound access is allowed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043795/dereferencing-an-out-of-bound-pointer-that-contains-the-address-of-an-object-ar

Comment: If I `delete` a pointer, call `new`, and by chance `new` gives me the same value, can I use the deleted pointer?

Comment: Regarding the "replacing the variable with another one" that David Schwartz mention mentioned, you can see that in action as part of an answer I wrote not long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31939212/1116364 There's a difference between conceptual constness and not being able to modify a memory location.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and cc Tony D: The standard explicitly states under which conditions you may use a pointer to an object whose storage has been reused to create another object. In the OP's case, the original object contains a `const` data member, and hence [basic.life]p7.3 says the pointer **does not** point ("refer") to the new object after the placement-new.

Comment: @dyp: the code in the question copies `p` to `q`, so it's not *"manipulat[ing] the new object"* using the old pointer `p`, but accessing it using the newly assigned `q`, with defined behaviour.  That that's significant is very interesting indeed.  I'll update my answer to highlight this - thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if overwriting the memory location (where object = region of memory + X) doesn't count as *manipulation*, but IMO the semantics of lifetime + `memcpy` are underspecified anyway. However, the pointer doesn't even "automatically refer to the new object" according to that paragraph.

Comment: @dyp: English is so easily ambiguous - to me *"a pointer that pointed to the original object...will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if"*... makes it sounds like the "automatically refer" bit is unconditional but the ability to manipulate is conditional.  Still, if it's this easy for people to interpret differently, compiler writers' takes may differ too and it'd be wisest to - at the very least - make the member non-`const` (better yet, to stop hacking up crappy code).

Comment: And the overwriting happens to the old object - it's manipulation of the new object that's potentially problematic, as that's through the pointer value whose trustworthiness we're discussing....

Comment: @TonyD The bullet-point requirements also cover cases where you have a pointer to a subobject, destroy the complete object of which that subobject was part of, and then create an entirely new complete object without that subobject (and different memory layout). E.g. `struct foo { int x; short y; }; struct bar { short x; float y; }; foo f; auto* px = &f.x; new(&f) bar;`

Comment: @dyp: yes - another reasonable exclusion - any particular reason you mention that in the context of this question, or just find it interesting...?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad example. `struct foo { short x; short y; }; foo f; auto* p = &f.y; auto* q = new((void*)&f) int(42);`, then `p` won't point to any object, especially not to `*q` (which is the new object). I think the bullet points intend to say that, but they only say it if the *automatically refer* is indeed conditional.

Comment: @dyp: *"The bullet-point requirements also cover cases where you have a pointer to a subobject"* - actually, I can't spot that in n3797 or n3690... in those, 3.8/7 starts "if...a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied"* - in your code above you're creating a new object at `&f` so the original object in question is `foo`, and continues *"a pointer that pointed to the original object"* - so we're talking about pointers to `&foo`; I'd hazard that excludes `p`, so the rest of the paragraph doesn't apply (neither "refer to" nor "manipulate").

Comment: @dyp `p` still refers to some (zombie) `short` object that's laying there without doing anything.

Comment: "_semantically pointing_" just means that a pointer can be dereferenced and you get the object it is semantically pointing to

Comment: @curiousguy: if you want to use terminology used in the C++ Standard or general Computing Science community that's all good, and the discussion will have a meaning other readers can easily follow.  But I'm just not interested in discussing C++ using terminology you've invented - it means others can't follow you without jumping around these comments, posts and answers and re-reading everything as they stumble across retrospective definitions of your terms.

Comment: @TonyD So tell me what the CS and std C++ terminology is.

Comment: @curiousguy I'm not commenting on whether there's a term that matches your exact notion, just that throwing terms around as if they will mean the same to others creates more confusion.  If you can't find one, and mean a pointer that can be dereferenced such that you access the object whose address it holds, say that.

Comment: @TonyDelroy I think the std C++ "throws around" terms by saying that the value of a ptr is fully determined by its bit pattern and they trying to say that some pointers are legal in some context but others are not, when they have the same value. It's a notion of "value" where the value of a variable doesn't determine the valid operations.

Comment: TonyDelroy: "_in some mystical sense_"  "_if you want to use terminology used in the C++ Standard or general Computing Science community that's all good_" funny

Answer (score 4):

This is only intended as an addendum to @Tony D's answer, regarding

> `new (p) Const(2)` erase the old object stored at `p`

I think you need to differentiate between an object and the conceptual idea of an "instance".

> [...] An object is a region of storage.[...]
>
> [N4431 §1.8/1]

So the pointer `p` points to a region of storage, which contains the bit pattern of some "instance" before the placement new and some different bit pattern of a different, but well constructed "instance" of the correct (same) type.

So at the location pointed to by `p` there's a valid object, and when assigning `q` from it `q` points to it. Though as noted in the other answer, accessing it via `p` isn't permited.

Comment: So this should works because I have not changed the type?

Comment: I'd guess so, yes. If you were constructing an object of a different type, then it would be UB to access that using a wrongly typed pointer.

Comment: So are OK with the fact that a `const int` takes different values?

Comment: The `const int` doesn't change value. It's two distinct `const int`s that happen to be at the same location in memory (at different times).

Comment: It is still a changing const from the point of view of the pointer.

Comment: Which pointer? Both are non const, so they can change what they point to.

Comment: That's kind of the point: `q` is modified in my code, so there is constness issue, and `p` isn't used after the modification. My objection does not apply to my code, it applies to your code.

Comment: What code exactly? In your code there's no issue. You modify `q`, which is perfectly fine, since it's **non const**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87324/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-daniel-jour).