# Is it UB to compare (for equality) a void pointer with a typed pointer in C?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, void-pointers, equality-operator

I have a typed pointer, `typed`, that was initialized using pointer arithmetic to point to an object within an array.  I also have a function that takes two pointer args, the 1st typed the same as the afore-mentioned pointer and the 2nd is `void *` (see `myfunc()` in the code below).

If I pass `typed` as the 1st argument and another pointer typed the same as `typed` as the 2nd argument, and then compare these for equality within the function, is that Undefined Behavior?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct S {int i; float f;} s;

void myfunc(s * a, void * b)
{
  if (a == b)  // <-------------------------------- is this UB?
    printf("the same\n");
}

int main()
{
  s myarray[] = {{7, 7.0}, {3, 3.0}};
  s * typed = myarray + 1;
  myfunc(typed, &(myarray[0]));

  return 0;
}
```

---

**Update:** Ok, so I come back a day after posting my question above and there are two great answers (thanks both to @SouravGhosh and @dbush). One came in earlier than the other by less than a minute (!) but from the looks of the comments on the 1st one, the answer was initially wrong and only corrected after the 2nd answer was posted. Which one do I accept? Is there a protocol for accepting one answer over the other in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comparison is well defined.

When a `void *` is compared against another pointer type via `==`, the other pointer is converted to `void *`.

Also, Section 6.5.9p6 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says the following regarding pointer comparisons with `==`:

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both
> are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and
> a subobject at its beginning) or function,both are pointers to one
> past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to
> one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the
> start of a different array  object  that  happens  to  immediately
> follow  the  first  array  object  in  the  address space.

There is no mention here of undefined behavior.

Comment: `void * operand is converted to the type of the other operand.`... 6.5.9p5?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Agh, I had it backwards.  Fixed.

Comment: no worries, that works for null pointer constant, not for `void*`s.

Comment: Note that in clang and gcc, the last kind of comparision described, "one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space" may result in behavior which is not only inconsistent with the comparison yielding 1, but also inconsistent with it yielding an unspecified value.

Comment: @supercat I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966762/can-an-equality-comparison-of-unrelated-pointers-evaluate-to-true) (which you also answered) on exactly that topic.

Comment: @dbush: The links to the gcc discussion were interesting.  It's claimed that the authors of the Standard thought the highest priority should be facilitating optimization, but I'm curious how many committee members actually think that, and how many thought it sufficiently obvious that top priority should be allowing the programmer to do what needs to be done, that it was only necessary to consider the priority of considerations that were secondary to that.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not undefined behaviour. This is allowed and explicitly defined in the spec for equality operator constraints. Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.5.9

> *one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void;*

and from paragraph 5 of same chapter

> *[...] If one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, the former is converted to the type of the latter.*

Comment: Sorry Sourav: in the absence of any feedback regarding how I should rule in such a "tie" as between yourself and dbush, I flipped a coin and dbush won.  Great answer though.