# Can a one past the element pointer that compares equal to a valid pointer be dereferenced?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

In C18 we have:

> ### § 6.5.9p10
>
> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are
> pointers to the same object(including a pointer to an object and a subobject
> at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element
> of the same array object, **or one is a pointer to one past the end of one
> array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array
> object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the
> address space**.

So for `int a[4][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}`,
we can have `a[1] == a[0] + 2`.

Can that by consequence guarantee that `*(a[1]) == *(a[0] + 2)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is **not** allowed to dereference such a pointer, even if it compares equal to another valid pointer.

Section 6.5.6p8 regarding the `+` operator states:

> When  an  expression  that  has  integer  type  is  added  to  or
> subtracted  from  a  pointer,  the result has the type of the pointer
> operand.  If the pointer operand points to an element of an array
> object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element
> offset from the original element such that the difference of the
> subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the
> integer expression.  In other words, if the expression `P` points to
> the i-th  element  of  an  array  object,  the  expressions `(P)+N`
> (equivalently, `N+(P)`)  and `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value *n*)
> point to, respectively, the *i+n*-th and *i−n*-th elements of the
> array  object,  provided  they  exist.   Moreover,  if  the
> expression `P` points  to  the  last element of an array object, the
> expression `(P)+1` points one past the last element of the array
> object,  and  if  the  expression `Q` points  one  past  the  last
> element  of  an  array  object,the  expression `(Q)-1` points  to  the
> last  element  of  the  array  object.  If  both  the  pointer operand
> and  the  result  point  to  elements  of  the  same  array  object,
> or  one  past  the  last element of the array object, the evaluation
> shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
> **If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*` operator that is
> evaluated**

On a related note, some compilers have the concept of *pointer provenance*, meaning it internally keeps track of the source of a pointer.  A consequence of this is that if two unrelated variables are adjacent in memory, comparing the address of one to one-past the address of the other will always evaluate to false, even if the addresses are the same.

Comment: *"some compilers have the concept of pointer provenance"* Sounds interesting, can you tell more? Which compilers do that?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966762/can-an-equality-comparison-of-unrelated-pointers-evaluate-to-true) I posted a few years back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you happen to know how this is covered in C++? I avoided tagging it as C++ and quoting its standard because in general here users reprove C/C++ questions. I suppose it'll lead to the same conclusion maybe, but it seems quite less explicit on this.

Comment: @pepper_chico In C++, `*` expects its argument to point to an object or function, so pointers past the end don't fit. It is indeed less explicit than in C.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I'm actually wondering whether it has the same pointer equality guarantee as in the illustration too, not only the dereference aspect (it's a corner case of one past the end).

Comment: @pepper_chico To be TBH, I don't think that either C or C++ guarantee that for `T arr[N][M];`, `&arr[0][M]` will compare equal to `&arr[1][0]`. But maybe I'm reading the standards too pedantically.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer your expression is indeed UB, because you're doing (final) dereference prior to getting address for the comparison. I don't do this in the example.

Comment: @pepper_chico That would actually be OK because `&arr[0][M]` is exactly the same as `&*(arr[0] + M)` and `&` immediately follow by `*` effectively cancel each other out as per 6.5.3.2p3 resulting in `arr[0] + M`

Comment: @pepper_chico In C, for `T arr[N];`, `&arr[N]` 100% is **not** UB. `E1[E2]` is equivalent to `*((E1) + (E2))`, i.e. `&arr[N]` is equivalent to `&*(arr + N)`, and the C standard says that if the operand of the `&` operator has the form `*E`, neither `&`, nor `*` are evaluated and the expression `&*E` is equivalent to `E`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer all OK, but C++ doesn't permit that, sorry about the confusion. But as both question and answer here show, comparison is valid in C. So no point in doubting that for C?

Comment: @pepper_chico I can rewrite w/o UB if you want: `arr[0] + M` and `arr[1] + 0`. And still I'm not 100% sure that these 2 pointers are guaranteed to compare equal by the Standard and it is not just a side effect of how pointers and their arithmetic is implemented in a typical implementation.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I thought my quotation with emphasis would be explicit enough guarantee, in C. If you're now only talking about C++, then yeah, I don't have something direct like that to be so sure.

Comment: @pepper_chico your emphasis just tells when pointers compare equal, but doesn't guarantee that `arr[1]` "happens to immediately follow" `arr[0]`. (No, I don't want to say that there can be padding "between" them).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer array elements are guaranteed to be contiguous (one adjacent to the other). I didn't see necessary to also quote that for the question.

Comment: @pepper_chico _array elements are guaranteed to be contiguous_ And what does this **really** mean? I mean, how can this be observed from a C program?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I think this side question is derailing the focus, maybe it's worth another SO question.