# Two different pointers pointing to the same address in C

Tags: c, pointers

I came across this very strange thing in this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float d = 12.432;
    float *pd = &d;
    printf("Value of d is %f\n", *pd);
    printf("Address of d is %p\n", pd);
    printf("Address of d+1 is %p\n", (pd + 1));
    printf("Value at d+1 is %f\n", *(pd + 1));

    int c = 1;
    int *yh = &c;
    printf("Value of c is %d\n", *yh);
    printf("Address of c is %p\n", yh);
    printf("Address of c+1 is %p\n", (yh + 1));
    printf("Value at c+1 is %d\n", *(yh + 1));

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this snippet in my machine the addresses of `d+1` and `c` come out to be the
[same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3yhK.png)
When I run on repl.it or some online compiler, I get different addresses as it should give.
What is the issue?

Comment: A pointer to a single object and a pointer to an array of objects looks the same.  The programmer has the burden to keep straight if a pointer is to an object or if a pointer is to an array (...and the length of that array).

Comment: `printf("Value at d+1 is %f\n", *(pd + 1));` is UB.

Comment: They could be same or they could not. It depends at which addresses your compiler puts the variables.

Comment: Why do you think they should be different? `d + 1` is not a valid pointer to `float` but in practice might be the place where the compiler allocates `int c`, although you can't rely on that (can't dereference said pointer). So don't ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of local variable allocation on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102049/order-of-local-variable-allocation-on-the-stack)

Comment: `(pd + 1)` is a valid address to report, as *one element past the storage allocation* is permitted.  But dereferencing that address with `*(pd + 1)` is *undefined*.

Comment: pointer in diffrent systems has diffrent size. in 64 bit systems it has size 8 bytes. but int and double has fixed size i think because of that you receive different address. and also all of this variables are in top of stack.

Comment: To lower the "noise" you should delete the last printf in both blocks as they are invalid. And they have nothing to do with your question

Comment: What is also undefined is comparing pointers to *different objects*.

Comment: @WeatherVane For relational operators yes, for equality operators no.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966762/can-an-equality-comparison-of-unrelated-pointers-evaluate-to-true

Comment: @WeatherVane It's worth noting that `std::less<>()` _et al._ have special magical powers to provide a total ordering for pointers for use in containers, _etc._, even if in general it isn't well-defined to compare unrelated pointers with plain `operator<` and co.

Comment: @underscore_d perhaps, but this is a C question.

Comment: With (pd + 1) and *(pd + 1) you are accessing the memory location that you didn't allocate for your program. But because pd is on the stack of your function frame typically the pd+1 could also be on the same stack frame. But your function doesn't own it in the form of a variable, so leave it alone or otherwise it has the power to crash your program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: The C standard does not require that pointers are directly related to memory addresses. However, it's how most modern systems work. This answer assumes such a system*

> in my machine the addresses of d+1 and c come out to be the same

I assume you mean: (the addresses of d)+1 and the address of c come out to be the same.

There is nothing strange about that.

When `pd + 1` is equal to `yh`, it simply means that the integer `c` is placed in memory just after the float `d`.

```
+---------+ <------- pd
|    d    |
+---------+ <------- pd+1 and also yh
|    c    |
+---------+ <------- yh+1
```

On another system it could be:

```
+---------+ <------- pd
|    d    |
+---------+ <------- pd+1
| unused  |
+---------+ 
| unused  |
+---------+
| unused  |
+---------+ <------- yh
|    c    |
+---------+ <------- yh+1
```

in which case `pd+1` differs from `yh`

> ... I get different addresses **as it should give**

Both cases are legal. One system may do the first case and another system the second case. So NO, it's not correct that it  "should give" different addresses.

BTW:

While it's legal to do `pd+1` it's illegal to dereference it like `*(pd+1)` because there is no float located there. So delete the line `printf("Value at d+1 is %f\n", *(pd + 1));` It's illegal and also irrelevant for the question.

The same applies to: `printf("Value at c+1 is %d\n", *(yh + 1));`

Comment: Ok so if I do something like
`*(pd+1)=2.1;`
after the 1st block, without declaring a specific variable for it, the value at the address `pd+1` gets re-written by `c`, rendering the 2.1 as useless

Comment: @SuhelKapadia Well... In principle yes but... `*(pd+1)=whatever` is illegal because there is no float variable at that address. It is called "undefined bahavior".

Answer (score 0):

**float** is a type whose size is 4 bytes.

When you perform pointer arithmetic, you calculate an address shifted from the original address by a number of times the size of the type.

i.e. **pd+1** points to an address **one** float after the variable d.

Typically your compiler may successiveily put all your declared variables in sequence in memory: d, pd, c and yh as they're declared in that order; but there is no guarantee there, it may chose to do otherwise.

If your compiler elects to place the variable d, then the variable c in two contiguous 32-bits space in memory, then typically, the following assertion will be true:

```
(pd+1) == &c
```

This seems to be your case. There is no problem with that.

Comment: Change d+1 -> pd+1

Comment: The size of float is irrelevant