# Is this write to an array truly undefined behavior in C?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, clang, undefined-behavior

This code writes a value through a pointer if one array is one past the end of another array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

extern int first[], second[];

#define ADDR_AFTER(ptr) ((uintptr_t)((ptr) + 1))

int test(int *an_int) {
    *second = 1;
    if (ADDR_AFTER(first) == (uintptr_t)an_int) {
        // ubsan does not like this.
        *an_int = 2;
    }
    return *second;
}

int first[1] = {0}, second[1] = {0};

int main() {
    if (ADDR_AFTER(first) == (uintptr_t)second) {
        printf("test: %d\n", test(second));
        printf("x: %d y: %d\n", *first, *second);
    }
}
```

At no point do I directly compare two pointers to different objects (because I convert them to `uintptr_t` first). I create a pointer to one-past-the-end of an array (which is legal), but I never dereference that pointer. As far as I can tell this should either print nothing, or print:

```
test: 2
x: 0 y: 2
```

Which is printed on Clang when optimization is `-O1` or lower. At `-O2`, however, it prints:

```
test: 1
x: 0 y: 2
```

With `-O2 -fsanitize=undefined` it prints the this to stdout:

```
test: 2
x: 0 y: 2
```

and the following to stderr:

```
runtime error: store to address 0x000000cd9efc with insufficient space for an object of type 'int'
0x000000cd9efc: note: pointer points here
  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

with a reference to the assignment to `an_int` in `test`. Is this actually undefined behavior, or is this a bug in Clang?

Comment: I suspect this is violating the strict aliasing rule. The optimizer assumes this doesn't happen.

Comment: The fact that optimizing makes it turn ugly is a good hint. Optimizing should never change the behavior of a well behaved program.

Comment: Strict aliasing doesn't apply here because `p` is a pointer to `int` that hasn't been marked `restrict`. It is therefore explicitly allowed to alias `y`.

Comment: @MichaelMorris Can you please rename your variables into something searchable so that talking about the code becomes easier? `p` ... not a good search item. Give them names ... proper ones!

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Renaming the one variable I mentioned is indeed better but .. do you want to make it easy for people to answer it or do you want to obscure the issues? Do one better please. Give all variables proper names.

Comment: your code is pretty convoluted. And you have different code for optimized and non-optimized which make it that much harder to follow. Right now I don't want to invest time to understand this code, but are you sure the difference you see in the optimized vs non-optimized code isn't cause because you have different code for optimized and non-optimized code via that preprocessor `#if #else`?

Comment: @bolov I've removed the check and can confirm that the issue is not caused by the `#if #else` I've also simplified the code.

Comment: Not quite a dup but closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966762/can-an-equality-comparison-of-unrelated-pointers-evaluate-to-true

Comment: Great job on simplifying the code. The code looks ok to me. There's no way `*an_int = 2;` is UB because `an_int` is just `second`.

Comment: fwiw, this shouldn't be `UB`; it is the normal exercising of pointer arithmetic.     You are only dealing with +1 pointers to array elements, and +1's have yet to be destroyed by standardization.  That said, the clown car is ready for another lap, so this could soon be UB.

Comment: Using the n4713 draft, the relevant part of the standard is section 8.5.10 paragraph (2.1): "If one pointer represents the address of a complete object, and another pointer represents the addressone past the last element of a different complete object,88the result of the comparison is unspecified."

but note that "unspecified" is not the same as "undefined".

Comment: This is a known compiler bug. There is an existing question on it; I will look for it. The compiler incorrectly “deduces” that when execution is inside the “then” clause of an `if (a == b)` that compares two pointers, then `a` and `b` must point to elements within the same “array” (using the definition of a “array” for the `==` operator, which treats a single object as an array of one element).

Comment: @o11c Does that mean that it would be conformant for the comparison to succeed in `main` but fail in `test`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Funny, I was converting to `uintptr_t` before the comparison specifically to avoid dealing with exactly that sort of bug.

Comment: @MichaelMorris: “If you lie to the compiler, it will get its revenge.” — Henry Spencer. Not an outright lie, perhaps, just a little attempt at subterfuge. Nonetheless, the compiler is displeased with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing invalid about your code, the compiler is wrong.  If you remove the unnecessary ADDR_AFTER check in `test()`, the code runs as expected with no UBSan error.  If you run it with optimization enabled and without UBSan, you get the wrong output (test=1, should be 2).

Something about the `ADDR_AFTER(first) == (uintptr_t)an_int` code inside `test()` makes Clang do the wrong thing when compiling with `-O2`.

I tested with `Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)` but it looks like Clang 13 and current trunk also have the bug: https://godbolt.org/z/s83ncTsbf - if you change the compiler to any version of GCC you'll see it can return 1 or 2 from `main()`, while Clang always returns 1 (`mov eax, 1`).

You should probably file a Clang bug for this.