# Can pointers with different provenance be equal?

Tags: c, pointers

Pointers with different provenance can be equal in a recent version of gcc:

```c
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int a[4];
int b[4];

int main() {
    puts(a+4 == b ? "equal" : "inequal");
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 13.2.1 20230801
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
equal
```

Is this behavior conformant with the c standard?

Comment: Do you have an underlying problem that leads to this question? Why do you need to check for such an equivalence? If you just ask out of pure curiosity, then that's fine, but please note so in the question. Otherwise please ask about the actual and underlying problem directly instead.

Comment: So, `b` is exactly after the end of `a`...I don't see the big deal, or the question. It's allowed. It's not disallowed. It's not surprising, but memory doesn't *have to* be adjacent.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Could be useful to determine padding between successive `struct` members.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is allowed to happen, but it's not guaranteed.

Section 6.5.9p6 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the equality operator states:

> **Two pointers compare equal if and only if** both are null pointers, both
> are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and
> a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one
> past the last element of the same array object, **or one is a pointer to
> one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the
> start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow
> the first array object in the address space.<sup>109)</sup>**
>
> ...
>
> 109. **Two objects may be adjacent in memory** because they are adjacent elements of a larger array or
>      adjacent members of a structure with no padding between them, **or because the implementation chose
>      to place them so, even though they are unrelated.** If prior invalid pointer operations (such as accesses
>      outside array bounds) produced undefined behavior, subsequent comparisons also produce undefined
>      behavior

Some compilers may have knowledge of pointer provenance and can use that knowledge to decide whether or not such a comparison is true.

See also: [Can an equality comparison of unrelated pointers evaluate to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966762/can-an-equality-comparison-of-unrelated-pointers-evaluate-to-true)

Answer (score 9):

> Does this behavior conformant with the c standard?

The provenance of pointer values does matter in some circumstances, but the C language makes no requirement or guarantee that pointers with unrelated provenance must compare unequal.  On the contrary, it says:

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both
> are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and
> a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one
> past the last element of the same array object, **or one is a pointer
> to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to
> the start of a different array object that happens to immediately
> follow the first array object in the address space.**

(C17 6.5.9/6; emphasis added)

It clarifies that:

> Two objects may be adjacent in memory because they are adjacent
> elements of a larger array or adjacent members of a structure with no
> padding between them, or because the implementation chose to place
> them so, even though they are unrelated.

(C17 footnote 111)

Comment: It is funny that the standard refers to the "other" pointer as the start of an *array* object. It could e.g. be pointing to a plain variable immediately following the array.

Comment: @nielsen IIRC, there are words somewhere which treat non-arrays objects as array objects of size 1 for this.  So all are covered.

Comment: @nielsen, chux is referring to C17 6.5.6/7: "*For the purposes of [pointer arithmetic, including array indexing], a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.*" Every version of the language spec contains substantially the same wording.  And that applies here because the only defined way to get a pointer to one past the end of an array object is by pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica and John Bollinger. That makes sense, though it is quite subtle when reading the clause in the answer out of context. Thank you both for the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome, @nielsen, and that's a point worth emphasizing: the language spec is a carefully crafted, integrated document.  Excerpts can be unclear or even misleading when interpreted outside the context of the whole spec.